# Steps to troubleshoot orders with no tax

Tags: tax

**Problem:**

I've had several orders that haven't charged the customer any taxes. I cannot duplicate the issue.

**What I've troubleshooted already:**

- Purchasing the same product
- Selecting / Entering the same details as customer (province + postal code)
- Selected same payment method

[image]
**Notes:**

- Has happened with different browsers and different operating systems (Windows, Android)
- All the products are assigned as  "Taxable Goods"
- Has happened to different provinces and different postal codes
- Orders before and after these orders without tax have charged the tax correctly.
- There are no errors in the logs corresponding to the date and time the orders were received.

**What additional steps should / can be taken in order to troubleshoot orders that have not been charged taxes?**

**Is there a method to look at the purchase itself to see what the problem is?**

Comment: Did you check customer groups?

Comment: Yes, I just double checked to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some major troubleshooting, it was found that there were FCGID errors in the log corresponding to the time that visitors were checking out. The calculations were interupted due to the crashing resulting in the in correct tax amounts.